# How to Initialize HtmlDiv

Tags: c#, initialization, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to pass `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls.HtmlDiv` as an argument so I need to initialize and find the specific control I'm looking for in one line (if possible) but I'm struggling to figure that out. Normal initialization is done like so...

```
HtmlDiv htmlDiv = new HtmlDiv(htmlDocument) // where htmlDocument is of Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl
htmlDiv.SearchProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Id] = "header";
```

I'm trying to do something like this...

```
myFunction(new HtmlDiv(htmlDocument) {
    SearchProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Id] = "header"
});
```

I'm getting the error `cannot resolve symbol 'SearchProperties'` and `Cannot initialize type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls.HtmlDiv' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'`.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure a way out to do this so I created a method in my HtmlDocument wrapper class that would return the found UITestControl.

```
public class UiHtmlDocument : HtmlDocument {
    public UiHtmlDocument(UITestControl searchLimitContainer) : base(searchLimitContainer) {}

    public T searchHtmlElementByAttributeValues<T>(Dictionary<string,string> propertyExpressions) where T : UITestControl, new() {
        var uiTestControl = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), this);
        foreach (var propertyExpression in propertyExpressions) {
            ((T)uiTestControl).SearchProperties[propertyExpression.Key] = propertyExpression.Value;
        }
        return (T)uiTestControl;
    }
}
```

and used like so...

```
myFunction(
    browserWindow.htmlDocument.searchHtmlElementByAttributeValues<HtmlDiv>(
        new Dictionary<string, string> { 
            { HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Class, "footer" } 
        }
    )
);
```